# Robolectric Unit Testing ClassCastException on Custom Layout

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-fragments, robolectric

I have "ClassCastException" on Robolectric Unit Testing when I test Activity or Fragment with Custom Layout or Custom Component on an android app.
Example : 
**CrumbView** that extends LinearLayout. When I start a fragment I got an error : 
***java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.test.ui.view.CrumbView cannot be cast to com.app.test.ui.view.CrumbView***
Does Anyone knows how to fix it? or it's not yet supported by Robolectric?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.test.ui.view.DrawerView cannot be cast to com.app.test.ui.view.DrawerView

at com.app.test.ui.activity.equipements.EquipementsActivity.onCreate(EquipementsActivity.java:61)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:232)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:58)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:364)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$1.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:26)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:55)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:65)
at com.app.test.ui.activity.equipements.EquipementsActivityTest.setUp(EquipementsActivityTest.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1846)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:810)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:675)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:76)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.invokeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:64)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:56)
at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:33)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:40)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:226)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:108)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:35)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:149)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

The Line onCreate(EquipementsActivity.java:61) is pointing :
**DrawerView drawerView = findViewById(R.id.drawer);**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_equipements);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    DrawerView drawerView = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle .......
```

Comment: Please add more details/code about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Just add "com.app.test.ui.view.*" to @PowerMockIgnore for your unit test.
e.g: 
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*", "com.app.test.ui.view.*"})

Comment: Why the -1? Works for me